# how to COUNT all colums?

Tags: sql, count

completley new to SQL, so apologies if this is basic, but while i can find article upon article explaining how to count a single column i can not find one that explains how to count all columns/cells containing a specific text.

i have a table with 3n0+ employee names as the colum headers. The colums contain attendance an employee id and an attendance log so each colum contains either a

1 = present
0 = absent

I;d simply like a query that will count all the 1's in each column (excluding column 1 as this is the employee code) and return the result (sum/count of all the 1's) and return the result for each column using the header (employees name.)

i.e. my table looks like:

| Ben | kate | Peter | Sally |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Result I want is:

```
BEN: 4
Kate: 2
Peter: 3
Sally: 5
```

Comment: Your table design is not very good because each additional person requires a new column.

Comment: your answer isn't very good as it failed to answer the question posed

Answer (score 0):

I agree about your bad DB design, you should to re-design it if it possible. If it is not you can use UNPIVOT pattern. You not labeled your question by RDBMS version, so I'll provide MS SQL example:

```
SELECT Employee, Cnt
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      SUM(Emp1) Emp1, SUM(Emp2) Emp2, SUM(Emp3) Emp3
 FROM T
) p
UNPIVOT
(
  Cnt for Employee IN
  (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3)
) AS upvt;
```

[Live test](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2022/cbd050d546659e6b93d7d3681f42a9f3/)